# Android CI using Bitbucket Pipelines and Docker

Tags: android, docker, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to set up Continuous Integration (CI) in [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) for Android.

I have created a sample blank activity using Android Studio 2.1.1.

With Pipelines I'm using the [uber/android-build-environment](https://hub.docker.com/r/uber/android-build-environment/) Docker container which creates the environment nicely. Here is my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
image: uber/android-build-environment:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - echo y | android update sdk --filter "extra-android-m2repository" --no-ui -a # Grab the Android Support Repo which isn't included in the container
          - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Some changes are needed since [uber/android-build-environment](https://hub.docker.com/r/uber/android-build-environment/) is expecting to be run like so:

```
docker run -i -v $PWD:/project -t uber/android-build-environment /bin/bash /project/ci/build.sh
```

For example, the source is not copied to the volume `/project` but instead Pipelines copies the contents of the Bitbucket repo to the working directory of the container at:

```
/opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build
```

And when `./gradlew assembleDebug` is run I get the following error:

```
...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type TaskArtifactStateCacheAccess using TaskExecutionServices.createCacheAccess().
> Failed to create parent directory '/opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build/.gradle' when creating directory '/opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build/.gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 56.449 secs
```

Running `ls -al` in the working directory gives:

```
ls -al
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 31 22:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 31 22:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 31 22:33 app
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  462 May 31 22:33 bitbucket-pipelines.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  498 May 31 22:33 build.gradle
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 May 31 22:33 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  387 May 31 22:33 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 31 22:33 gradle
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  855 May 31 22:33 gradle.properties
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4971 May 31 22:33 gradlew
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2314 May 31 22:33 gradlew.bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   15 May 31 22:33 settings.gradle
```

Comment: I did not find other alternative than using the `uber/android-build-environment:latest` Docker image to build and Android Gradle-based projet using Bitbucket Pipelines. Are there any other ways to do it ? Did you solve your issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. This seems to be an issue with Pipelines not the build container.

Comment: @RyanR I new to CI integration having trouble with android development setup so if possible can you help me out in with setting CI with Bitbucket pipelines

Comment: @RyanR Join this room to talk more http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46117/ci-intergeation-with-docker

Comment: can anybody explain what are the process happens while bitbucket-pipelines started running?  uber/android-build-environment Docker container will be downloaded to our local machine ?

Comment: @LOG_TAG When you push changes to your Bitbucket project (with a bitbucket-pipelines.yml file present) then the Docker image specified in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml (in this question they were using uber/android-build-environment Docker) will be downloaded and run on Bitbucket Pipelines (on their build servers, not your local machine). This answer might help make it more clear: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40055055/196486

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bug in their system , I report it([issue url](https://support.atlassian.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/11/BBS-33852#), it's quite long) to them and they have fixed it ([fix url](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12956/i-cant-write-to-build-directory-when-user)).I have tested on my project and it successfully build.Try to build your project now and good luck.

Comment: Thanks, yes the project now builds successfully.

Comment: why I'm getting _+ ./gradlew assembleDebug
bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory_

Comment: @RyanR can you share the working bitbucket-pipelines.yml file? and where I have to put _docker run -i -v $PWD:/project......._ ? in the yml file only I have to put this! Any info will be grateful.

Comment: The `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` in the question should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `uber/android-build-environment` is not supported anymore.

I ended up using `javiersantos/android-ci` instead which works perfectly from scratch.

Just add the following content to *bitbucket-pipeline.yml:*

```
image: javiersantos/android-ci:27.0.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
          - chmod +x ./gradlew
          - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/uber/android-build-environment/ page still exists.

Comment: @RyanR it exists, but it is outdated (last update happened 2 yers ago). One can't build SDK 27 based project using their image.

Comment: As of June 2019, Uber's Docker image for Android is [unmaintained and unsupported](https://github.com/uber-archive/android-build-environment). There are other Docker images to use, like [MingChen](https://github.com/mingchen/docker-android-build-box) and [danylovolokh](https://github.com/danylovolokh/Setup-Free-Bitbucket-Cloud-CI). More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806261/android-environment-using-docker-and-bitbucket-pipelines

Comment: I recommend to use the androidsdk/android-30 image. More details here: 
https://1gravityllc.medium.com/ci-cd-for-android-using-bitbucket-pipelines-and-gradle-play-publisher-f00d6047ecb5

Answer (score 0):

Could you symlink your project from `/opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build` to `/project` from within the container? `ln -s /opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build /project` is the command you'll need.

or alternatively copy the files to the new path?

I have no experience with android development, so YMMV :)