# android environment using docker and bitbucket pipelines

Tags: android, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I am very new to Bitbucket pipelines (Beta) and docker.No previous experience on CI integration

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557551/android-ci-using-bitbucket-pipelines-and-docker) question , But no clear description for beginners

I am trying to set up Continuous Integration (CI) in Bitbucket Pipelines for Android Project using [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/uber/android-build-environment/)

I want to use my previous android project with this container

Steps I followed

**Step 1**. Installed Docker Software tools . Successfully installed.

**Step 2**. Created Virtual Machine Successfully

**Step 3** . Created container from Kitematic (Beta) [Uber/Android-Build-Environment](https://hub.docker.com/r/uber/android-build-environment/)

[image: Successfully Docker full]

**Step 4**. Build Project Successfully using

```
$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"

$ docker build -t uber/android-build-environment .
```

[image]

**Step 5**. Change working directly to android project

***Step 6. Problem is in this step while running this command***

```
docker run -i -v $PWD:/project -t uber/android-build-environment /bin/bash /project/ci/build.sh
```

**Error come** :

**`/bin/bash: /project/ci/build.sh: No such file or directory`**

[image: Error Image]

**Docker-machine details**

```
docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.12.1
```

**Docker Service**

```
docker service ls
```

**Docker Machine ENV**

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.XX.XXX:XXXX"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/gaurav/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval $(docker-machine env)
```

Answer (score 24):

If I understand your question correctly: you technically don't even need to install [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) on your local machine in order to use it in your Bitbucket Pipelines (although it can be quite helpful for debugging).

Bitbucket Pipelines can be configured to use a Docker from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/), and the one you mentioned ([uber/android-build-environment](https://hub.docker.com/r/uber/android-build-environment/)) worked well for me.

Simply add a `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` to the root of your project, for example:

```
image: uber/android-build-environment:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - build.sh
```

I like to organize my build process in it's own ash script file (`build.sh`) but that is *optional* (you could instead put multiple bulleted commands in the [yaml](http://yaml.org/) file under the `script` directive). Examples of (and more details about) the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file can be found on the [Language guides for Bitbucket Pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/language-guides-for-bitbucket-pipelines-856821477.html) page.

My `build.sh` script (also in the root of the project, but could be placed in a subdirectory as long as you refer to it as such in your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`, e.g. `scripts/build.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir "${ANDROID_HOME}/licenses" || true
echo "8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "${ANDROID_HOME}/licenses/android-sdk-license"

./gradlew assembleDebug
```

The licenses portion allows the Android Gradle process to automatically download Android dependencies for you, as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381577/196486).

For good measure, [set the permissions on the build script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21694391/196486) accordingly:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x build.sh
```

Make sure that you've enabled Bitbucket Pipelines (from your repo page: `Settings` -> `Pipelines: Settings` -> `Enable Pipelines`).

Then just commit the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` and `build.sh` and push to your BitBucket repo. The Bitbucket Pipelines build for your project should begin shortly after your push. The Bitbucket Pipelines will download the `uber/android-build-environment` Docker from Docker Hub and checkout your project and run the `build.sh` script within the Docker.

---

The process you were describing of setting up the Docker on your local machine can be really helpful if your Bitbucket Pipelines build fails and you want to have the same environment running on your local machine so you can experiment with it and test changes to the `build.sh` script before actually committing and pushing to your repo.

Might also prove helpful if you ran (locally):

```
docker run -it uber/android-build-environment
```

Which will start up the Docker (on your local machine) and put you in an interactive shell, so that you can browse around and gain a better understanding of the Docker environment.

Also note that the Bitbucket Pipelines clones your repo in the Docker as part of the build process (which as far as I could tell) you had not done on the Docker running on your local machine, which may have led to some of your confusion about your `build.sh` script not being present.

If you want a directory on your local machine to exist within a Docker (that you are running on your local machine, perhaps to test building a project on your local machine within a Docker you want to use) you can use the following command to mount your current working directory to `/project` within the locally running Docker:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/project -it uber/android-build-environment
```

More details can be found at [Mount a host directory as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume).

As @ming-c pointed out in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40294677/196486), there are many other Docker images available on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/); it is certainly worth browsing around to see if you can find an image best suited to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for very good explaining answer , I would try this and confirm is it working or not .

Comment: `chmod +x build.sh` - should this be executed inside the builder or on my local machine? I would assume inside the build environment, but then I get a `Operation not permitted` If I have to set on my local machine, how can I execute chmod on windows?

Comment: @morpheus05 I updated the answer to use a command that should work on all platforms. The command should be executed on your local machine, basically telling git to store the fact that `build.sh` should be executable (so when the project is cloned by Bitbucket Pipelines for the Docker, `build.sh` will be executable).

Comment: I followed this but can't make it work, it fails saying: 'You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components: [Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.1, Android SDK Platform 25].' Previously I needed to modify the yml, particularly in the build.sh line to: 'bash ./build.sh', otherwise it said permission denied. Same to ./gradlew assembleDebug, I modified to 'bash ./gradlew assembleDebug'. Any ideas of what could be happening?

Comment: The error log ends with: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:[Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.1, Android SDK Platform 25].Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager. Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Comment: @GabrielPiffaretti did you follow the instructions in the linked Stackoverflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381577/196486), it describes how to retrieve the hashes of your accepted licenses from your desktop for use in your CI process. I haven't tried it, but it also shows how to have the licenses accepted automatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45782695/196486

Answer (score 20):

uber's image is built for their CI environment, I created [a typical docker image only include Android build env](https://github.com/mingchen/docker-android-build-box). It included the latest SDK and NDK. You can just use following example as your bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: mingc/android-build-box:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          - chmod +x gradlew
          - ./gradlew assemble
```

You can also used in GitHub Actions by specific `container`:

```
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    container: mingc/android-build-box:latest
```

It include following components:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Android SDKs

  - 25
  - 26
  - 27
  - 28
  - 29
  - 30
- Android build tools:

  - 25.0.0 25.0.1 25.0.2 25.0.3
  - 26.0.0 26.0.1 26.0.2
  - 27.0.1 27.0.2 27.0.3
  - 28.0.1 28.0.2 28.0.3
  - 29.0.2 29.0.3
  - 30.0.0
- Android NDK r21
- Android Emulator
- TestNG
- Python 2, Python 3
- Node.js, npm, React Native
- Ruby, RubyGems
- fastlane
- Kotlin
- Flutter

You can also use this docker image to build your Android project with a single docker run command:

```
cd <android project directory>  # change working directory to your project root directory.
docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/project mingc/android-build-box bash -c 'cd /project; ./gradlew build'
```

Comment: I ran into this problem `Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain` can you give me any clue?

Comment: Which version of gradle you used ? Can you build in your local env ?

Comment: I use the newest build tool ver 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'. Gradle version is 3.3. It can build with my Android Studio. Do you have a sample repo with sample app which is successfully integrated with pipeline?

Comment: Yes, @thuanle, I have integrated to pipeline successfully, the config is exactly the same as here.

Comment: Can you share that sample app on Bitbucket? So I can clone and figure problem myself.

Comment: I am sorry it is a private repo. You can try to build in your local by docker pull the image and run command to help you debug your project settings:
docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/project mingc/android-build-box bash -c 'cd /project; ./gradlew build'

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try

Comment: I figured it out. I need to add `gradle-wrapper.jar` in `git add -f gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` to the repo. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you need Android SDK 26, Android NDK 15, Android Emulator, Cordova, or Ionic, you can check my fork of his repository on [github](https://github.com/boris-penev/docker-android-build-box) and [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/borispenev/docker-android-build-box/).

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this guide:**

https://github.com/danylovolokh/Setup-Free-Bitbucket-Cloud-CI

It is quite exhaustive, it shows how to:

1. Update build number, build version name etc...
2. Update build.gradle
3. Commit and push changes to the repository
4. Collect a changelog
5. Build the application

Additional steps:

6. Sign the application with the "release" signing key.
7. Upload the apk files to the storage for future usage.
8. Upload a version to the Fabric Beta for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Your command `docker run -i -v $PWD:/project -t uber/android-build-environment /bin/bash /project/ci/build.sh` assumes the file `/project/ci/build.sh` is on the container. Are you sure you're running this docker command from the directory that contains it?

If you're not sure I would try the (from your project directory)

`docker run -it -v $PWD:/project uber/android-build-environment /bin/bash`

and then check the results of `ls -a /project` when you get logged into the container.

Another thing to make sure of is that `build.sh` is allowed to be executed, make sure of this by running `chmod +x build.sh` on it.