# Android - What is continuous integration for mobile and what is the best way to do it in Android?

Tags: android, continuous-integration

I have seen some continuous integration providers such as amazon AWS and Jenkins with Firebase.

but which one is the best with easy configurations and for free ?

Answer (score 0):

[Continuous Integration](https://www.thoughtworks.com/continuous-integration), in simple terms, is the practice of having your builds automated by a system; and, you have that system build your app many times a day.

**Steps**:

- You push a change, or someone pushes a change,
- the build system (jenkins, travis, circle, etc) gets triggered,
- it runs your tests,
- the system builds your APK,
- then, it notifies you if everything works (or if something breaks)

By `continuous integrating` on a regular basis, you detect errors quicker and you locate them more easily - and since you're doing it multiple times a day you know as soon as possible when something goes wrong.

---

**Which to choose**:

> ...the best way to do it in Android?

I don't know about the 'best' way - when opting out from paying for it. I'm assuming you're using Android Studio, if so, Firebase would probably be the 'easiest' one to configure and use. This is because Firebase [Test Labs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/continuous) comes with continuous integration and Firebase is deeply integrated with Android Studio.

As a bonus, if in the future you decide to change to from Jenkins to [Circle CI](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/firebase-test-lab/), you can also use it with Firebase.

If you want another option, don't forget to look at the [Github](https://jenkins.io/solutions/github/) plugin for Jenkins - It doesn't necessarily have to include Firebase but it gives you another option.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55212214/1748464

I describe how to setup a freen CI for Android based on Bitbucket Pipelines.